# How to make an object "stick" to another even after resize?

Tags: objects, transforms, snapping

I'm trying to make a model of a coin with numbers on its face.

Lately, I had to change the coin thickness but the problem is that the numbers just sink into it, instead of staying "glued" to its face.

Original:
[image]

More thickness:
[image]

Sure, I could manually move the numbers but I'd rather make it so that they always stay "glued" to the face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your text out of a plane, use Shrinkwrap modifier to stick it to the surface, and then after that give it thickness with Solidify:

[image]

It's also possible to parent objects to vertices of a mesh. You need to select the object you want to be the child, the parent object, enter edit mode, select vertices you want to use and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier for someone to help if you could have attached your .blend file to your question using: https://blend-exchange.com/

I'm not sure if what I suggest is what you want to do. You have to convert the text to mesh for it to work.

I started with this setup:
[image]

It looks like your second image shows the origin in the middle of the Z axis, similar to what this image shows:
[image]

I used the method in this image to convert the text to mesh:
[image]

My text is .4 inches high. I raised it .2 inches on the Z axis, so that the bottom was aligned with the bottom of the cube and the 3D cursor:
[image]

I used the method in this image to move the origin to the 3D cursor:
[image]

With this result:
[image]

Then with these settings:
[image]

I used G->Z to snap to the corner vertex with this result:
[image]

Or, using this setting, I used G->Z to snap to the face:
[image]

Comment: I didn't know I could attach files, thanks! But the other answer seems easier to implement.

Comment: I'm glad that you got a solution.